# Removed Google Play Billing AIDL completely but google play developer console still show warning

Tags: android, google-play-console, google-play-billing

I have a question about the google billing library.

Before, following the instructions of Google Play,
We have migrated from Google Play Billing AIDL to Google Play Billing Library version 3.

However, when I upload the aab file to the Google play developer console, I still get the following warning:

> The app has detected that it is using an unsupported version of the
> Play Billing service. To publish this app, please upgrade to Google
> Play Billing Library version 3 or later.

If you know how to identify the cause or you can guess the general cause of this case, please give us some advice.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Update Your dependencies:

```
implementation ('com.android.billingclient:billing:4.0.0')
```

If the error stiil persists, try to add this lines in Your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.play.billingclient.version"
    android:value="4.0.0" />
```

Comment: The metadata based one, works best! Regarding which version to use, this link was helpful https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/deprecation-faq