# Unable to access subscriptions tab in google play console

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-console, subscription

I am currently working on adding subscriptions to my android app using React Native. However, when I click on the subscriptions tab all I see is "Upload a new APK"

[image]

When clicking on this button, I am simply navigated to the closed testing tab rather than the subscriptions tab.

[image]

I am attempting to integrate subscriptions with revenue cat but am unable to do so as I cannot navigate to the subscriptions tab. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also I have already included this line in my Manifest:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line to AndroidManifest.xml with the other "uses-permission" tags.

`<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />`

Create a new app bundle with this tag added, upload it to Google Play Console, and add create a new release.

The button to create a new subscription will then be available in the subscriptions page.

(The "In-app products" page in Play Console has a better error message for this. That's how I found the solution for myself.)

**edit (I just noticed you're using revenuecat)**
The revenuecat package should add this for you. Create a new build after including revenuecat in your project.
**

Comment: If you face billing library version issue from console after doing this step, the following link would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69582987/removed-google-play-billing-aidl-completely-but-google-play-developer-console-st/69935672#69935672